# AttributeError when using TfidfVectorizer in a SKLearn pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I have the following code to combine the results of an NLP model and a quantitative model with a StackingClassifier:

```py
# Feature Selection pipelines
NLP_COLS = ['processed_text']
KNN_COLS = ['retweet_count', 'favorite_count', 'num_hashtags', 'num_urls']
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
combined_tweet_df['processed_text'] = combined_tweet_df['processed_text'].astype(str)
pipe_nlp = Pipeline([
    ('select', ColumnTransformer([('sel', 'passthrough', NLP_COLS)])), 
    ('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer),
    ('clf', nlp_model)
])
pipe_knn = Pipeline([
    ('select', ColumnTransformer([('sel', 'passthrough', KNN_COLS)])),
    ('clf', knn_model)
])

# stacking ensemble
stacking_model = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=[
        ('nlp', pipe_nlp),
        ('knn', pipe_knn)
    ], 
    final_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(), 
    cv=5
)

# train test split
x_train, x_test = train_test_split(
    combined_tweet_df[['processed_text', 'retweet_count', 'favorite_count', 'num_hashtags', 'num_urls']],
    test_size=0.25,
    random_state=4
)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(combined_tweet_df['type'], test_size=0.25, random_state=4)

stacking_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

However, at the `stacking_model.fit` I run into the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you told `sklearn` to remain the `DataFrame` by setting  `set_config(transform_output="pandas")`? See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_1_2_0.html#pandas-output-with-set-output-api

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback, please.